# ImportError: cannot import name 'GenerationMixin' from 'transformers.generation' while running executable file creating using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, huggingface-transformers

There is the original code, i want to use fine-tuned mT5 model to summarize :

```
# code.py 
def summarize(article_text):
    model_name = "csebuetnlp/mT5_multilingual_XLSum"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    # the next line is the bug
    model = torch.load('t5_summary.pt')

    input_ids = tokenizer(
        [WHITESPACE_HANDLER(article_text)],
        return_tensors="pt",
        padding="max_length",
        truncation=True,
        max_length=512
    )["input_ids"]

    output_ids = model.generate(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        max_length=84,
        no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
        num_beams=4
    )[0]

    summary = tokenizer.decode(
        output_ids,
        skip_special_tokens=True,
        clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False
    )
    return summary
```

[image]

How to resolve the problem?
Please tell me!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/9750) and this [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/9515), you should install the `sentencepiece` and `protobuf` package. For the latter make sure you install an older version:

```
pip install sentencepiece   
pip install protobuf==3.20.0
```

After that you can use the model like this:

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

```
model_name = "csebuetnlp/mT5_multilingual_XLSum"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

Now the error is gone.

Comment: While running the executable file, where the bugs occurs is following:
`
model = torch.load('t5_summary.pt')
`
I need to use the model i fine-tuned.